# Printing BarCode Fail c# winform and zen.barcode framework

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, barcode-printing

I'm Having problem printing a barcode in c# winform

this is my code:

\GENERATING BARCODE

```
 Code128BarcodeDraw codigoDeBarra = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
                    codigo = equipo.Codigo1;
                    categoria = equipo.Categoria1;
                    imagenCodigo  = codigoDeBarra.Draw(codigo, 20);
```

\AND PRINTING

```
        private void imprimir(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //chkImprimir.CheckState == CheckState.Checked
            if (chkTest.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                FrmEquipos frmequipos = new FrmEquipos();
                frmequipos.txtCodigo.Text = codigo;
                frmequipos.Show();

            }
            else
            {
               
                Font font = new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 5, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                int width = 200;
                int height = 280;
                int x = 70;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("cca", font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(x + 5, 6, width, height));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagenCodigo, new PointF(x, 25));
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(textoConAsteriscos, customFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(x, yPosCodigoBarras));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(codigo, font2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(x, 48, width, height));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(categoria, font1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(x + 45, 50, width, height));
            }
```

\PRINT CLICK

```
 private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cantidadimprimir = (int)txtCantidadImprimir.Value;

            printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = ps;
            printDocument1.PrintPage += imprimir;
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)(int)cantidadimprimir;
            printDocument1.Print();

            LimpiarCampos();
        }
```

**I'M USING zebra zd410 and zebra zd421..**

I put the barcode into picturebox and show it in the winform and looks good but when I printing it's loog bad here picture:

[In picturebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2TJZ.png)
[Printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F31hZ.jpg)

Comment: Wild guess: check your print settings. If the settings make a logical pixel fat enough, you might get what you are seeing.

Comment: I'm using a zebra zd410 and zebra zd421 I dont see an option for logical pixel

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: I didn't expect that there'd be a setting with my made up concept of "virtual pixel". I only wanted to give you hint about might be the issue

Comment: I use the dpi as describe in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0 and nothing if i save it in PDF its look good :(, theres another barcode framework just to prove it?